# Creating vectors using an input file in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to read the data from a text file and store it in some vectors. Here is the input file and the code:

Input file:

```
3
0 Paul
1 Peter
2 David
0 3 Chicago Boston Memphis
1 1 Boston
2 0
```

The first line "n" represents the number of people. The next "n" lines represent the ID number, and name of each individual. The next "n" lines use the ID number, then the number of cities "num_c" each person wants to visit, then all "num_c" cities.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    if (!infile.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Error: could not open file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int n;
    infile >> n;

    vector<string> names(n);
    vector<int> num_places(n);
    vector<vector<string> > places(n);

    // Read names
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int id;
        string name;
        infile >> id >> name;
        names[id] = name;
    }

    // Read places
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int id;
        int num;

        infile >> id >> num;
        num_places[id] = num;
        vector<string> temp(num);

        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            string place;
            infile >> place;
            temp[j] = place;
        }
        places[id] = temp;
    }

    // Print out the vectors to check that they were populated correctly.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        cout << "Person " << i << ": " << names[i] << endl;
        cout << "Places they want to visit: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < num_places[i]; j++)
        {
            cout << places[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The names read into the vectors correctly, but the cities do not. When the output is ran
at the end, it correctly identifies each person by ID, but the "Places they want to visit:" is always empty. Thank you for your time.

Comment: As for your problem maybe you need to set a breakpoint at `infile >> place;` and step through your code 1 line at a time looking at the variables and flow after each step to see what is happening.

Comment: Hmm. Seems to work here without files: [https://ideone.com/NIfkPI](https://ideone.com/NIfkPI)

Comment: You have a super fancy unicode En SPACE characters (0xe2 80 82) in your file. Retype it with a dumb text editor, not a fancy word processor.

Comment: Ahh, I did notice some weird character / symbol between the numbers when converting the data file to text so I could put the data in the code and use istringstream instead of files. I replaced it with a space. That is probably why it worked for me..

Comment: On a side note, think of what would happen if a person wants to visit a city that has a space in its name, like `Los Angeles` or `San Diego` or `New York`. This code will fall apart on those cities. If that is ever a possibility, you should change the text file to delimit the cities with say `'\t'` tab characters instead, and then use `std::getline('\t')` instead of `>>` to read them. Same with people names that have spaces in them, use `std::getline()` instead of `>>`.

Comment: @Mat that was it! I retyped it all and it worked out! Thank you!